# How do I hide a secret from other users?

Tags: c++, security, encryption, passwords

I want to store a user passkey (which has to remain in cleartext to be sent to the server) in a way that other users of the same machine wont have access to it even though they have access to the program. What is the best way of doing this (platform independent is best, second is a small platform dependent section (e.g. some function `getCurrentUserSecret()`), and last is a completely platform dependent solution such as Windows Data Protection API).

Comment: What's wrong with encrypting it?

Comment: get the user to provide one?

Comment: It's meant to be used as an auto-login feature based on the systems currently logged in user. Having the user input a password would defeat the purpose of the feature.

Comment: Sending it in cleartext eliminates any potential security gains from encrypting it locally. Anyone on the same network could read it, potentially opening the "secret" to an even wider audience than the users of the current machine.

Comment: @jpaugh it isnt sent in cleartext. it is sent via SSL/HTTPS (but the cleartext password is visible to the server).

Comment: Oh. Well, of course. Carry on, then. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to transmit it in clear text why not just store it in clear text, in a location where only the user in question has read access to the file. I don't think there's any way to solve your problem in a way that the administrator/root couldn't circumvent, even with encryption (unless for example you have the user enter another password to decrypt a stored cleartext password).

EDIT for comment: I'm not aware of any OS that does anything like compute an alternate "hashed" password value at login, and store it in memory. Even if it did, root could *Still* access that memory to get the hash value and the OS would have to take particular care to make sure that any such chunk(s) of memory could never be committed to swap.

Comment: This isn't correct; there is a way to do this such that even root cant get access. The reason is that you assume that all information is accessible to root. The key information that isnt shared with root is the cleartext of the user's password. If the OS were to MD5 that (or some other hash whose result isnt stored on disk) that would make an adequate symmetric key to encrypt/decrypt data on a per-user basis.

Comment: @chacham15 so it's ok for the user to enter their OS password another time?

Comment: yes, at login (this feature eliminates the redundency of 'logging in twice'). All I want is a way to access this 'user specific hash' to use as a symmetric key.

Comment: For edit: That is how the Windows DPAPI works. I do not know of a *nix  equivalent (and hence the question). Furthermore, when you say "root could Still access that memory" that would require that the user actually be logged on (which is at least some protection that it would not otherwise have, and on windows is a solid bet since there is no root equivalent).

Comment: @chacham15: On Windows any member of the Administrators group has completely unrestricted (super user) access to the system, just like `root` does on Unix and Linux systems.  The access may not be direct, but a user with permission to load new kernel drivers can do anything.  You're right that even an administrator would have to wait for the user to login in order to access data encrypted using the user's password, but that's not much of a reassurance.